# GDAL gdalbuildvrt throws error:- CalledProcessError: Command returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, gdal, osgeo

I am mosaicking about 50 image tiles in a .img format. The file paths are arranged in an ascending order in a text file. I want to use gdalbuildvrt to build virtual dataset mosaic. Since the each file is about 1.5 GB in size, the mosaic would be ~75GB.

As I run the gdalbuildvrt in my python script or in command line.

The formats which I have tried are shown below:

```
os.system("gdalbuildvrt -input_file_list text1.txt text1VRT.vrt")
```

What can be the reason for this error?

On running the subprocess.check_call() function, the following error is shown:

```
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Is it that the gdalbuildvrt function cannot be found?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue, the problem was that the input file text1.txt had the list of files not on separate lines. So when reading the .txt file, it was reading the whole file contents as a single file name, thereby running out of the memory buffer.

Second issue - non zero exit status 1 was because the text file with list of path has quotation marks that were being read by gdalbuidvrt and thus making the file path invalid.